# Сравнить 2 массива с объектами и отдать один целый

Tags: javascript, массивы, filter

Есть 2 массива, которые нужно сравнить

```
let arr = [
    {id:1},
    {id:2},
    {id:3},
    {id:4}
];

let newArr = [
    {id:2},
    {id:3},
    {id:4},
    {id:5},
    {id:6}
];
```

на выходе должен получится один массив со следующими значениями:

```
let result = [{id:2},
              {id:3},
              {id:4},
              {id:5,new:true},
              {id:6,new:true}
             ]
```

объект {id:1} - должен соответственно из нового массива удалиться

Наброски..

```js
var arr = [{
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4
  },
];

var newArr = [{
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4
  },
  {
    id: 5
  },
  {
    id: 6
  }
];


var props = ['id'];

var result = newArr.filter(function(o1) {
  // filter out (!) items in result2
  return !arr.some(function(o2) {
    return o1.id === o2.id;
  });
}).map(function(o) {
  return props.reduce(function(newo, id) {
    newo[id] = o[id];
    newo.new = true;
    return newo;
  }, {});
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3},
    {id: 4}
];

let newArr = [
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3},
    {id: 4},
    {id: 5},
    {id: 6}
];

const res = newArr.map((a1) => {
  if (!arr.find(a2 => a1.id === a2.id)) {
    a1.new = true
  }
  return a1; 
});

console.log(res);
```